# The next statement runs before the former one ends

Tags: javascript

I run these code on my firefox, and the `console` gets `3 2 1`, which means statements run before the former ones end.

```
function test(){
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(1)},1000);    //statement 0
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(2)},500);     //statement 1
}
test();
console.log(3);                                     //statement 2
```

Is it a feature of javascript, and do I have to double-check a variable after assigning it some value? Cuz' it's way too complicated.

```
var a;
while(a!==get('some')){
    a=get('some');
    if(a===get('some')){
       whatShouldBeRun();afterGetSome();
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is exactly what you have asked it to do. Firstly, you ask it to kick off two statements to run some point in the future. Then you write "3". The first of those statements whose time it is to run then runs, and writes "2". Finally, the third of these runs and writes "1".

If you are using asynchronous processing - settimeout - then yes you need to handle this as with any other language. But then if you need it to run in order, don't tell it to run asynchronously.

To get them to run one after the other:

```
function test()
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        console.log(1);setTimeout(function()
           {
                  console.log(2);console.log(3)
           },500)
    },1000);
}

test();
```

[I might have some of this wrong]

Comment: I use `setTimeout()` to stimulate a functions which take a long time, like network or sql queries. How am I able to know if a function is running asynchronously, say a function adding large numbers or processing huge texts?

Comment: The timeout explicitly runs asynchronously. As do ajax calls. It very much depends what sort of call you are making. If they do run async, then you will have to amend your processing to handle this. See edits to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I've got a clue at lease :)

Answer (score 1):

The above code starts two [timers](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), which will fire after 500 and 1000 milliseconds. `console.log(3);` will run first, with no delay; after 500 milliseconds, `console.log(2)` will be executed, and after another 500 milliseconds, comes `console.log(1)`. This is the general general way how timers work in any language/framework which contains timers.

Sequential code runs in order, that is, subsequent lines of code are executed in series. Event-based systems, like web browsers and their JavaScript implementation, are different in that event handlers are executed only when the event happens. The code `test(); console.log(3);` is executed sequentially: two timers are started by calling `setTimeout` with the given intervals and event handlers, and `3` is written to the console. The "tick" event of the first timer comes after 500 ms, and its event handler function will write `2` to the console. The "tick" event of the second one comes after another 500 ms, and will write `1`.